# Django User Management: how to avoid that each user sees content and data from other users?

Tags: python, django, django-users

In my small Django project, users can sign up and by filling in some ModelForms they can populate the existing Models with their own data. 
The problem is that upon logging in, any user can see not only their own data, but also the data created by other users. 
I need to avoid that.
Every user should be able to see, modify and interact exclusively with their own data. 
Every Model has the attribute user which is a `ForeignKey` linked to `User`. 
Am I possibly missing something in the views? 
They're just class based views that do no refer to `User`, they just have the `LoginRequiredMixin` decorator.

For the login views I'm using Django standard, and for register view I have created a `UserFormView`.

```
# Register page
url(r'^register/$', views.UserFormView.as_view(), name='register'),

# Login page
url(r'^accounts/login/$', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(), name='login'),
```

Here are my views:

```
class AllProgramsView (LoginRequiredMixin, generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'programs/index.html'
    context_object_name = 'programs_list'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Program.objects.all()

class ProgramDetailView (LoginRequiredMixin, generic.DetailView):
    model = Program
    template_name = 'programs/program.html'

class ProgramCreate(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Program
    form_class = ProgramFormClass

class ProgramUpdate(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    model = Program
    form_class = ProgramFormClass
```

In `models.py`:

```
class Program(models.Model):
    program_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    program_description = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    is_favourite = models.BooleanField(default="False")
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('programs:program', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})

    def __str__(self):
        return self.program_name
```

Is there a correct procedure to be implemented to keep each user separated from the others?

Comment: you can use request.user to differentiate that which user is requesting data

Comment: could you post your views. with that people can respond more cleary

Comment: Hi @Rajez I've just edited my question to include the views.

Comment: How a query on Program model is different for every user? Would you mind posting your Program Model

Comment: @ArpitSolanki hi, yes I'll add the model. To answer your question, every user can create their own programs and in the list view they should be able to see all the programs they've created. The problem now is that all the users see all the existing programs (created by other users as well) instead of just their own as it should be.

Comment: @Giulia see the answer below.

Comment: @ArpitSolanki I've added the code suggested but I get the error NoReverseMatch at /programs/
Reverse for 'create_program' not found. 'create_program' is not a valid view function or pattern name. Any clue?

Comment: @ArpitSolanki it works now, after clearing browser cache. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get the current user, who is requesting the view and filter their records only as by the following

```
class AllProgramsView (LoginRequiredMixin, generic.ListView):
 template_name = 'programs/index.html'
 context_object_name = 'programs_list'

 def get_queryset(self):
    user = self.request.user
    queryset = Program.objects.filter(user=user)
    return queryset
```

Comment: In my Program model (I've added it to the question in case you want to check it) I have the field user with a ForeignKey relationship with User model. I tried following along your suggestion by adding `code`user = self.request.user   queryset = Program.objects.filter(user=user) return queryset but it does not work. Is there anything wrong in this piece of code?

Comment: Cleared browser cashed and refreshed, it worked! Thank you so much.